# Sharing object context Tasks

Tags: c#, multithreading, thread-safety, task-parallel-library, .net-4.5.2

I have a list lstSubscriptionRequests  on which indivisual items i am doing some sort of processing asynchronously. Then after All items are processed i have to return the updated list items. My current implementation is like

```
List<SubscriptionRequest> lstSubscriptionRequests = FromSomeResource();

 var tsk = new List<Task>();
                foreach (var oTsk in lstSubscriptionRequests.Select(objSubscriptionRequest => new Task(
                    () => ProcessSubscriptionForASingleRecord(objSubscriptionRequest))))
                {
                    oTsk.Start();
                    lock (tsk)
                    {
                        tsk.Add(oTsk);
                    }
                }
                Task.WaitAll(tsk.ToArray());
```

It's looks like some of the items after all the tasks completed are not updated.
Please let me know what correction i needed

Comment: Don't create a task by yourself, use `await` or `Task.Run`. Your tasks aren't starting at all

Comment: Can you help me in correcting the above code?

Comment: Why are you creating cold tasks like this and why are you using `lock` when you are *still* on the main thread? Your code doesn't contain `Parallel.ForEach` either, or any attampt to share state. It's impossible to answer like this. Eg `Parallel.ForEach(lstSubscriptionRequests,ProcessSubscriptionForASingleRecord)` is equivalent to this code. Why don't you use it? If `ProcessSubscription..` produces results use PLINQ, eg `from subscription in lstSubscriptionRequests.AsParallel() select ProcessSubscriptionForASingleRecord(subscription)`

Comment: Please explain what you want to do, not how you tried to do it.

Comment: I were having a Parallel.For each within which i am starting tasks. Now I have removed it

Comment: @KamranShahid why? `Parallel.ForEach` itself uses tasks. Why create *more* ? Did you encounter a problem? What was it? `Parallel.ForEach` isn't broken, nor does it require manual creation of tasks

Comment: @KamranShahid please explain what you are trying to do. There haven't been any answers in 4 days, not because people don't know, but because the question isn't clear and the code is *weird*. Not only does it try to immitate `Parallel.ForEach`, it's full of problems, like using cold tasks. Unclear questions don't get answers, no matter how much time passes

Comment: I like to close it but can't

Answer (score 2):

You could accomplish this much easier. Note that using the Task constructor is not typically necessary or recommended, also mutating the state of a particular object can be difficult to follow or debug. Returning a new object that represents your desired state will allow you to enforce a minimum valid state.  The following code will processes all your items and return the completed items to your client code.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Processing {
    public class MyProcessor {

        public async Task<IEnumerable<Subscription>> ProcessSubscriptionRequestsAsync(IEnumerable<SubscriptionRequest> subscriptionRequests) {
            var subscriptionProcessingTasks = subscriptionRequests.Select(request => ProcessSubscriptionForASingleRecord(request)).ToArray();
            return await Task.WhenAll(subscriptionProcessingTasks);
        }

        public async Task<Subscription> ProcessSubscriptionForASingleRecord(SubscriptionRequest request) {
            //process the request
            try {
                var subscription = await Context.ProcessRequest(request);
                return subscription;
            } catch {
                //something went wrong with the request
            }
        }
    }

    public class SubscriptionRequest {
        //A subcription request
    }

    public class Subscription {
        //A completed subscription request
    }
}
```

**Update**

> It could help if you could exclude new Class Subscription and add the solution in your answer. i will then try it out

Hopefully the simplified before and after view will be easier to integrate. The primary difference is replacing the `Parallel.ForEach` with a `Select` to create your collection of tasks without needing to take a lock on the task list for every `SubscriptionRequest`, also spooling up `Task`s in parallel isn't typically necessary as each one will be executing asynchronously you only gain reaching a point where all are *waiting* sooner, not *finishing*. Next each tasks is allowed to start and all are awaited at `await Task.WhenAll(tasks)`. It will be important for you to determine what type of processing each `SubscriptionRequest` undergoes. For the sake of example i"ve made the assumption that each request is somehow linked to database access, i.e. storing the request, updating a user profile of sorts etc..

```
public class OriginalSynchronous {

    public void ProcessSubscriptionRequest() {
        List<SubscriptionRequest> lstSubscriptionRequests = FromSomeResource();

        List<Task> tsk = new List<Task>();
        Parallel.ForEach(lstSubscriptionRequests, objSubscriptionRequest => {
            var oTsk =
                new Task(
                    () => ProcessSubscriptionForASingleRecord(objSubscriptionRequest));// update some properties after processing SubscriptionRequest
            oTsk.Start();
            lock (tsk) {
                tsk.Add(oTsk);
            }

        });
        Task.WaitAll(tsk.ToArray());
    }

    private void ProcessSubscriptionForASingleRecord(SubscriptionRequest request) {
        //modify SubscriptionRequest
    }
}

public class ModifiedAsync {

    public async Task ProcessSubscriptionRequest() {
        var subscriptionRequests = await FromSomeResourceAsync();
        var tasks = subscriptionRequests.Select(request => {
            return ProcessSubscriptionForASingleRecord(request);
        }).ToArray();
        await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
    }

    public async Task ProcessSubscriptionForASingleRecord(SubscriptionRequest request) {
        //modify SubscriptionRequest
    }
}
```

Comment: Can't get it why i have to make another class subscription?

Comment: @KamranShahid you don't _have_ to, `ProcessSubscriptionForASingleRecord` could just as well modify `SubscrptionRequest` like your original code.  Doing that will allow you to remove the manual `Task` creation, unnecessary `lock`, and the unnecessary `Parallel.ForEach` that caused problems in the original code. Adding `Subscription` was just a suggestion for a further refinement of the code, it is not strictly required.

Comment: It could help if you could exclude new Class Subscription and add the solution in your answer. i will then try it out